# grep: When should the kleene star(*) match itself?

Tags: linux, grep, kleene-star

I am learning `grep` atm but I am having difficulty understanding the working of the kleene star metacharacter. The man pages describe that the `*` matches previous character zero or more times. I am using a file named `test` with the following content

```
*a
123ab
1234
abcdef
a?
?
```

`grep 'a*' test` should match zero or more occurrences of `a` and as explained prints every line of the `test` file in the output.
The document further describes that to match metacharacters like `*` they have to be escaped by preceding them with a backslash `\`.
But the output from `grep '*' test` and `grep '\*' test` is same. Output: `*a`
Why is `*` matching itself without preceding it with `\`?

Comment: I believe that `*a` is not a valid grep pattern (since it is an invalid regexp). How grep deals with that in perhaps "undefined behavior" and implementations can do what they want (and handling that initial `*` as verbatim is sensible)

Comment: But `grep '\*a' test` matches it perfectly. .

Comment: Because `\*a` is a valid regexp

Comment: I'd be disinclined to call something an invalid regex, and talk about undefined behaviour, unless you can actually point to a standards document that details how regexes are supposed to work. Especially when there is a vast difference amongst various implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` on its own is an invalid regular expression since there is no previous item to repeat. Your implementation of grep, in this case, interprets it as a literal `*`. `\*` is a valid regular expression which matches a `*`. Your implementation's interpretation of the invalid regular expression `*` and the valid regular expression `\*` just happen to be the same.

If you really want to see the difference between `*` and `\*`, you should try it on a valid regular expression by adding an item before it. For example, a literal `a`:

```
grep 'a*'
grep 'a\*'
```

The former will match anything since `*` can match zero characters successfully. The latter will only match lines containing `a*` literally.

Comment: Invalid? According to what standard, exactly? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The one in my head that happens to mostly match what common regular expression engines do.

Answer (score 3):

A leading `*` in a regular expression is valid according to [section 9.3.3 of SUSv3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). Naruto, your platform's regular expression interpreter is doing the right thing here: `*` is not a special character when it is at the start of a regular expression.